# No runnable export preset found for this platform

Tags: android, godot

When I am trying to export to Android I get this error.

> No runnable export preset found for this platform.
> Please add a runnable preset in the Export menu or define an existing preset as runnable.

[image: No runnable export preset found for this platform. Please add a runnable preset in the Export menu or define an existing preset as runnable.]

Following is all I get in the output:

--- Debugging process started ---

Godot Engine v3.3.3.stable.mono.official.b973f997f - https://godotengine.org
OpenGL ES 3.0 Renderer: Quadro T1000/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL ES Batching: ON

--- Debugging process stopped ---

**UPDATE**

Following are my export settings :

[image: Export Settings]

Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us your Export settings?

Comment: @hardartcore Updated please take a look

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I was asking about the settings from the menu: Project -> Export scene. Did you add Android as option there?

Comment: I am not able to find any such setting @hardartcore, Am I missing something?

Comment: Where are you searching those settings? They should be available in top left corner of GogotEngine when your project is open.

Comment: Oh wait i think i found it give me sometime i will get back to you

Comment: It will probably ask you to download export template and after that you can create an Android Runnable and export an apk or abb.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments in order to build and export for Android you should add `Android Runnable` in Export settings in Project -> Export -> Add -> Android. It will probably ask you to download export template and once it's done you will be able to build an Android apk or aab.